# Error after login in M2 Backend in dev mode only

Tags: magento2

Anybody experience with this error? I see nothing in the logs that helps me.

> Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid
>   Document  Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but
>   missing. Line: 5
>
> 0 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also experienced this issue some time ago. Actually, the problem is one of your custom or third party module contains `<resource>` tag in `acl.xml` in `etc` folder file and the `title` attribute is missing over there, which is the cause of this exception. Therefore, I would suggest you to check `acl.xml` files and if `title` attribute is missing in any of your module then add a `title` to `<resource>` tag something like this:

File **`etc/acl.xml`** in one of your module:

```
<resource id="Custom_Module::config" title="Module Title" />
```

You can also check this [Magento 2.2.0 Invalid Document Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195080/magento-2-2-0-invalid-document-element-resource-the-attribute-title-is-requ) from where I found the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I had disabled all MSI modules.
Try to enable them and check if this fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to verifying the title against the most inner resource tag, also verify that you have not added extra `id="Custome_Module::config"` in any of your `acl.xml` or some spelling mistake etc.